# Unit testing never run after setup UI testing Xcode 7

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I set up UI testing `MyProjectUITests` in Xcode 7 and I also added a new unit test in to target `MyProjectTests`. However, when I typed `Command + U`, it seems like Xcode always testing my project with UI Testing.

**Question:** How could I choose to build specifically for UI testing or unit testing if need ?

Answer (score 4):

Select your scheme.
Edit scheme ->Test- > Add Unit test with '+' button

[image]

To choose to build specifically you can check/uncheck the checkbox under Test.